# MySQL does not work after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04

I had Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I upgraded successfully to Ubuntu 20.04. MySQL stopped working and this is what I get now:

```
root@jaimemontoya:/etc/mysql# sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2023-07-28 23:45:19 UTC; 5s ago
    Process: 9620 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 9628 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server upgrade in progress"
      Tasks: 28 (limit: 1043)
     Memory: 375.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─9628 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jul 28 23:45:19 jaimemontoya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 28 23:45:19 jaimemontoya systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 28 23:45:19 jaimemontoya systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

I think MySQL was automatically upgraded. This is what I see now:

```
root@jaimemontoya:/etc/mysql# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

How can I restore MySQL to make it work without having to delete it and lose the databases that I already had?

UPDATE 1:

While the upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 was in progress, I noticed the moment when something went wrong with MySQL. This is the screenshot:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

This is the MySQl log taken from `var/log/mysql/error.log.1`. The problem started to happen at 2023-07-28T22:28:24.869862Z, which was when the MySQL error of the screenshot in my UPDATE 1 appeared.

```
2023-07-28T22:28:24.869862Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 11184
2023-07-28T22:28:24.927457Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2023-07-28T22:28:24.927600Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-28T22:28:24.997895Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012681] [InnoDB] page_aligned_alloc mmap(137236480 bytes) failed; errno 12
2023-07-28T22:28:24.999801Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012956] [InnoDB] Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2023-07-28T22:28:25.000111Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-07-28T22:28:25.000175Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2023-07-28T22:28:25.001901Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-07-28T22:28:25.002297Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-28T22:28:25.016545Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2023-07-28T22:28:26.476073Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 11213
2023-07-28T22:28:26.531156Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2023-07-28T22:28:26.531410Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-28T22:28:26.611957Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012681] [InnoDB] page_aligned_alloc mmap(137236480 bytes) failed; errno 12
2023-07-28T22:28:26.619722Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012956] [InnoDB] Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2023-07-28T22:28:26.619788Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-07-28T22:28:26.619823Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2023-07-28T22:28:26.628529Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-07-28T22:28:26.628574Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-28T22:28:26.636853Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2023-07-28T22:28:27.853591Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 11291
2023-07-28T22:28:27.900644Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2023-07-28T22:28:27.900803Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-28T22:28:27.948119Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012681] [InnoDB] page_aligned_alloc mmap(137236480 bytes) failed; errno 12
2023-07-28T22:28:27.948413Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012956] [InnoDB] Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2023-07-28T22:28:27.948437Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-07-28T22:28:27.948478Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2023-07-28T22:28:27.949279Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-07-28T22:28:27.949300Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-28T22:28:27.951133Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2023-07-28T22:28:29.128482Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 11313
2023-07-28T22:28:29.191428Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2023-07-28T22:28:29.191648Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-28T22:28:29.240615Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012681] [InnoDB] page_aligned_alloc mmap(137236480 bytes) failed; errno 12
2023-07-28T22:28:29.240703Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012956] [InnoDB] Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2023-07-28T22:28:29.240722Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-07-28T22:28:29.240945Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2023-07-28T22:28:29.241396Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-07-28T22:28:29.241413Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-28T22:28:29.244356Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2023-07-28T22:28:30.354378Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 11324
2023-07-28T22:28:30.398454Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2023-07-28T22:28:30.398643Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-28T22:28:30.459265Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012681] [InnoDB] page_aligned_alloc mmap(137236480 bytes) failed; errno 12
2023-07-28T22:28:30.459502Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012956] [InnoDB] Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2023-07-28T22:28:30.459528Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-07-28T22:28:30.459565Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2023-07-28T22:28:30.460578Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-07-28T22:28:30.460604Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-28T22:28:30.464152Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2023-07-28T22:28:31.496447Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 11336
2023-07-28T22:28:31.545067Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2023-07-28T22:28:31.545153Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-28T22:28:31.579957Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012681] [InnoDB] page_aligned_alloc mmap(137236480 bytes) failed; errno 12
2023-07-28T22:28:31.580797Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012956] [InnoDB] Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2023-07-28T22:28:31.580833Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-07-28T22:28:31.580874Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2023-07-28T22:28:31.582826Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-07-28T22:28:31.582853Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-28T22:28:31.588335Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2023-07-28T22:28:32.286958Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 11347
2023-07-28T22:28:32.336055Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2023-07-28T22:28:32.336277Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-28T22:28:32.379048Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012681] [InnoDB] page_aligned_alloc mmap(137236480 bytes) failed; errno 12
2023-07-28T22:28:32.380367Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012956] [InnoDB] Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2023-07-28T22:28:32.380417Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-07-28T22:28:32.380572Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2023-07-28T22:28:32.382049Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-07-28T22:28:32.382080Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-28T22:28:32.386812Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
```

UPDATE 3:

I increased the memory of the server and ran `systemctl restart mysql`. No response and this is what I see in the error log:

```
2023-07-29T07:27:04.125361Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement '-- -- Upgrade help tables -- ALTER TABLE help_category MODIFY url TEXT NOT NULL; ' failed with error code = 3664, error message = 'Failed to delete SDI 'mysql.help_category' in tablespace 'mysql'.'.
2023-07-29T07:27:04.140213Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
2023-07-29T07:27:04.141280Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-07-29T07:27:05.133064Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4)  (Ubuntu).
2023-07-29T07:27:05.803636Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) starting as process 2033
2023-07-29T07:27:05.820378Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-07-29T07:27:06.327560Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-07-29T07:27:06.824143Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '50700' to '80033' started.
```

UPDATE 4:

I brought the content of `/etc/mysql/` (image below) from my server with Ubuntu 20.04 and MySQL 8.0 where MySQL is not working, to a virtual machine I created with Ubuntu 18.04.02 and MySQL 5.7. I am trying to implement the solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367859/18-04-lts-20-04-lts-leaves-mysql-broken-unsupported-upgrade-path provided by matigo: "Fire up a VM, install MySQL 5.7 (yes, 5.7), stop the database, copy your existing /etc/mysql files to the VM's data directory, start MySQL and have it upgrade your tables..."

[image]

UPDATE 5:

Within `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/` I do not have files named `help_category` that I can MOVE to a folder outside `/var/lib/mysql` and then try to start MySQL. But I do see my databases. If there is a way to restore them manually somehow from what I have in `/var/lib/mysql/`, that would solve my problem even if I have to uninstall MySQL and then reinstall it in the same or another server, for any version of MySQL.

```
root@jaimemontoya:/var/lib/mysql# ls -al
total 799204
drwx------  9 mysql mysql      4096 Jul 29 13:23  .
drwxr-xr-x 80 root  root       4096 Jul 29 08:53  ..
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql        56 Nov  6  2021  auto.cnf
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql         0 Jul 28 22:28  binlog.index
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql      1680 Nov  6  2021  ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql      1112 Nov  6  2021  ca.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql      1112 Nov  6  2021  client-cert.pem
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql      1676 Nov  6  2021  client-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql         0 Jul 28 22:28  debian-5.7.flag
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql      4096 Jul 29 09:40  finance
drwxr-x---  2 root  root       4096 Jul 29 09:51  financeCOPY
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql    196608 Jul 29 13:23 '#ib_16384_0.dblwr'
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql   8585216 Jul 29 08:50 '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql       727 Jul 28 22:09  ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  79691776 Jul 29 13:23  ibdata1
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  12582912 Jul 29 13:23  ibtmp1
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql      4096 Jul 29 13:23 '#innodb_redo'
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql      4096 Jul 29 13:23 '#innodb_temp'
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql      4096 Jul 29 08:53  mysql
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 364904448 Jul 29 12:57  mysql.ibd
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql         6 Jul 29 13:06  mysql_upgrade_info
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql      4096 Jul 28 22:49  performance_schema
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql      1676 Nov  6  2021  private_key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql       452 Nov  6  2021  public_key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql      1112 Nov  6  2021  server-cert.pem
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql      1676 Nov  6  2021  server-key.pem
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql     12288 Jul 28 22:49  sys
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 100663296 Jul 29 12:57  undo_001
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 251658240 Jul 29 12:57  undo_002
root@jaimemontoya:/var/lib/mysql# ls -al mysql/
total 56
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql  4096 Jul 29 08:53 .
drwx------ 9 mysql mysql  4096 Jul 29 13:23 ..
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 12503 Jul 29 08:48 @0023sql@002d16b9_4_24859.sdi
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  5971 Jul 29 08:53 general_log_24881.sdi
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql    35 Jul 29 13:06 general_log.CSM
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql     0 Jul 29 08:53 general_log.CSV
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 12500 Jul 29 08:53 slow_log_24883.sdi
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql    35 Jul 29 13:06 slow_log.CSM
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql     0 Nov  6  2021 slow_log.CSV
root@jaimemontoya:/var/lib/mysql# ls -al finance/
total 2140
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql   4096 Jul 29 09:40 .
drwx------ 9 mysql mysql   4096 Jul 29 13:23 ..
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 DimBank.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 DimBuyer.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 DimCardBrand.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 163840 Jul 28 22:49 DimCard.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 DimCardType.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 DimCategory.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 DimCity.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 DimCountry.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 DimDay.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 131072 Jul 28 22:49 DimPaymentMethod.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 131072 Jul 28 22:49 DimProvince.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 DimSeller.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 147456 Jul 28 22:49 FactPurchases.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 180224 Jul 28 22:49 FactPurchasesXDimCategory.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114688 Jul 28 22:49 FactSales.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 180224 Jul 28 22:49 FactSalesXDimCategory.ibd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   36306 Jan 20  2019 mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   36306 Jan 20  2019 mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb.1
root@jaimemontoya:/var/lib/mysql#
```

Comment: What does the mysql log show as errors? `/var/log/mysql/error.log` or similar path?

Comment: Also note that SO is for programming problems. Please try asking at [askubntu.com](https://askubntu.com) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) or [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: You can ask here such questions. So the cause can be seen in the error log, there you will find also a link or you get at least new search patterns, if you post your error log here we can take a look

Comment: Even if you uninstall and reinstall MySQL, your databases will not be affected.

Comment: @Ron The log is in UPDATE 2 that I added to the body of my question.

Comment: @nbk Thank you. The log is in UPDATE 2 that I added to the body of my question.

Comment: The MySQL server must be reconfigured, you try to allocate memory that you don't have see https://bobcares.com/blog/innodb-fatal-error-cannot-allocate-memory-for-the-buffer-pool/

Comment: @nbk Would increasing the memory of my server to an amount that is big enough, and then running `systemctl restart mysql`, fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, that would help the problem but you still should read about innodb memory and it's parameters

Comment: @nbk Increasing memory on the server did not fix the issue. See my UPDATE 3. I feel that the root cause is that Ubuntu 20.04 installed MySQL 8.0, and I need MySQL 5.7. I am trying the solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367859/18-04-lts-20-04-lts-leaves-mysql-broken-unsupported-upgrade-path about installing a VM with MySQL 5.7. Now I want to move `/etc/mysql` of my server with Ubuntu 20.04 where MySQL is not working, to my VM with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and MySQL 5.7. But I am not being able to transfer that folder with FileZilla. It says "Error: local: unable to open /etc/mysql/...`.

Comment: That is a new question, why didn't change the parameter like the link explained. For your VM , you can link external folder to the VM see the manual, and in the MySQL.ini you can make the linked folder the tablespace

Comment: @nbk The approach of moving `/etc/mysql/` from my server that was upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and has MySQL broken, to `/etc/mysql/' of a virtual machine environment with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and MySQL 5.7, is a workaround to be able to read and backup my database. It is not a new question. My ideal scenario is to fix MySQL in the server that I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04.2 to Ubuntu 20.04. I think that somehow I need MySQL 5.7, so I guess I would need to downgrade from MySQL 8.0 to MySQL 5.7, in Ubuntu 20.04, if that is possible.

Comment: I do not think copying over /etc/mysql is a good idea.. So please create a backup of `/var/lib/mysql` to another safe place, so you can restore if needed. And then check if within `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/` you have files named `help_category` ? If you do MOVE them to a folder outside `/var/lib/mysql`, and try to start mysql

Comment: You will need to later restore or recreate the table, and use `check table help_category for upgrade;` to fix the meta data for it

Comment: @Ron See UPDATE 5 in my question. Within /var/lib/mysql/mysql/ I do not have files named help_category. But if I could restore databases from /var/lib/mysql/finance, from those .ibd that I see in that folder, that is all I need. Then I can delete and reinstall MySQL in the same, or any other server.